# Hiding tab in Vue.js if if-statement is true

Tags: javascript, vue.js, if-statement, tabs, show-hide

I have a Vue component which has a template that goes like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="row" >
      <button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-bottom:20px" @click="changeSelectedComp">Back</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left:1000px" @click="EditMode">Edit</button>
    </div>

    <vue-tabs>
      <v-tab title="Basic">
        <app-players></app-players>
      </v-tab>
      <v-tab title="History">
        <app-histories></app-histories>
      </v-tab>
      <v-tab title="Timetable">
        <app-timetables></app-timetables>
      </v-tab>
      <v-tab title="Scholarship">
        <app-scholarship></app-scholarship>
      </v-tab>
    </vue-tabs>
  </div>
</template>
```

What I want to achieve is to hide the tabs `History`, `Timetable` and `Scholarship` if this statement is true:

```
IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup("Admins", function (isCurrentUserInGroup) {
    if(isCurrentUserInGroup) {
        // hide the tabs
    }
});
```

This is the `IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup` function:

```
function IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(groupName, OnComplete) {

    var currentContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var currentWeb = currentContext.get_web();

    var currentUser = currentContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
    currentContext.load(currentUser);

    var allGroups = currentWeb.get_siteGroups();
    currentContext.load(allGroups);

    var group = allGroups.getByName(groupName);
    currentContext.load(group);

    var groupUsers = group.get_users();
    currentContext.load(groupUsers);

    currentContext.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccess,OnFailure);

    function OnSuccess(sender, args) {
        var userInGroup = false;
        var groupUserEnumerator = groupUsers.getEnumerator();
        while (groupUserEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var groupUser = groupUserEnumerator.get_current();
            if (groupUser.get_id() == currentUser.get_id()) {
                userInGroup = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        OnComplete(userInGroup);
    }

    function OnFailure(sender, args) {
        OnComplete(false);
    }
}
```

I looked at `v-if` (Conditional rendering), but haven't understood the syntax. 
Tried `<vue-tabs v-if="IsCurrentMemberofGroup">`, but it wouldn't work.

How can I hide the tabs if the if statement is true?
(Here's the [full component](https://codeshare.io/aVM06R))

Comment: <vue-tabs v-if="IsCurrentMemberofGroup"> will render if IsCurrentMemberofGroup is true, to render if IsCurrentMemberofGroup is not true use <vue-tabs v-if="!IsCurrentMemberofGroup">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `isCurrentUserInGroup` inside the data so that you can refer to it:

```
export default {
        components: {
            ...
        },
        methods: {
            ...
        },
        data: {
            isCurrentUserInGroup: false
        }
    };
```

and set to to true or false wherever it's needed.
Then you can use it with `v-if` in the tabs:

```
<vue-tabs>
      <v-tab title="Basic">
        <app-players></app-players>
      </v-tab>
      <v-tab v-if="isCurrentUserInGroup" title="History">
        <app-histories></app-histories>
      </v-tab>
      <v-tab v-if="isCurrentUserInGroup" title="Timetable">
        <app-timetables></app-timetables>
      </v-tab>
      <v-tab v-if="isCurrentUserInGroup" title="Scholarship">
        <app-scholarship></app-scholarship>
      </v-tab>
    </vue-tabs>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I still don't understand where to put this `IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup("Admins", function (isCurrentUserInGroup) {
    if(isCurrentUserInGroup) {
        // hide the tabs
    }
});`

Comment: You could call the method from the `created()` lifecyclehook.